# Cocoa Mac open source control for displaying guided product tours

Tags: macos, cocoa, controls

A couple of months ago, I found an open source cocoa control for displaying guided product tours for cocoa apps on the net. It can be used to highlight parts of a Mac application by displaying floating arrows that contain instructional text.

I've looked on cocoacontrols.com and cocoapods, but I can't find it anymore and I don't remember the name.

Does anyone have a link to this ?